# Blazor: Define namespace in Razor File

Tags: c#, blazor, razor-component-library

Question: Is there a way to define a namespace in a .razor file in Blazor.

Problem Explanation: Razor files in Blazor do not have a namespace defined (only the code behind class has one and it should match the .razor file location in the project). This resulted in a problem on GitHub and it restrict me from offering a Razor Component Library with few namespaces.

Github problem: This stems from a Microsoft philosophy I do not subscribe to: filenames are not case sensitive. I had a folder, lets say it was named 'FooBar'. In my project I renamed it 'Foobar'. Either Windows did not rename it properly, or when checking in in Github it was not seen as a change. As a result, my code behind namespace 'Foobar' no longer matched the namespace of my /razor file 'FooBar', resulting in a build error on Github (it worked fine on my pc). If I had been able to specify the namespace in the .razor file this would not have happened.

Component library problem: I am making a component library I want to offer on NuGet. I want to keep all my components in separate folders (let's say for Single responsibility sake). When I now want to include this component library, the _imports file will have a `@include` for each folder that is part of the library, again because I am unable to separate working with folders from the namespace the components are in. I would like to say `@include Foobar` rather than `@include Foobar.Checkbox`, `@include Foobar.Radiobutton` etc, etc.

So is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Ok I did not find this googling (It might be somewhere though) but I tried the following:

In the code behind rename the namespace Foobar.Checkbox to Foobar
in the razor file add `@namespace Foobar`

Yes it is that simple *facepalm*

Comment: Thanks for posting this. Namespace definition is required to add a blazor component to a layout or page, and the lack of explicit namespace definition in most pages (esp. template-generated layouts) is confusing because it seems inconsistent.

Comment: For anyone having issues with the Microsoft tutorial for creating a WPF/Blazor Hybrid project, this is what allowed the .razor file in my root to be found.

Answer (score -1):

By example. Your Blazor component name is Box, in folder Boxes.

You namespace should be Boxs - Right?

Do this:
Add a class in Boxs folder with name Box.razor.cs. This class is the C# code of Box, then add to this class:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace Boxes;

public partial class Box: ComponentBase
{
// @code ...
}
```

To make easy, add the Boxs namespace to _imports.razor.

Comment: You are confusing me and probably other people. You use Box, Boxes and Boxs.
Also your logic is not ... well logically. Why would I want to name it Boxes and not Shapes or ProjectName.Shapes or anything else.
Your code is correct but this post was how to use a namespace in a razor file, not the partial class in the code behind.